# Chart Control customlabel alignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I've been away from .Net developping for like 6 years, coming back and I had to create a chart, I was really pleased to see this control, but the way it works is kinda annoying, anyway, look at this picture:
[image: 2 charts]

These are two charts, both the same one, the only difference is their width and height, but as you can see, on the smaller on, the labels are unaligned.
At first I had the same problem with the bigger one, but increasing the distance between the from and to points when including the customlabel fixed it, however the same trick doesn't seem to be working for the smaller one.
The points are added this way (these are random points added directly for now, it'll become automated in the future)

```
serie1.Points.AddXY(1, 2000);
            area.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(0.5, 1.5, "1");
            serie1.Points.AddXY(2, 20000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(3, 30000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(4, 40000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(5, 60000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(6, 55000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(7, 59000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(8, 70000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(9, 90000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(10, 80000);
            area.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(9, 11, "10");
            serie1.Points.AddXY(11, 100000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(12, 95000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(13, 80000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(14, 75000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(15, 89000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(16, 110000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(17, 105000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(18, 115000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(19, 120000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(20, 130000);
            area.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(19, 21, "20");
            serie1.Points.AddXY(21, 115000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(22, 110000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(23, 120000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(24, 125000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(25, 124000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(26, 135000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(27, 140000);
            serie1.Points.AddXY(28, 155000);
            area.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(27, 29, "28");
```

serie1 is the blue line, area is the ChartArea.
Anyone knows how I could make sure that the labels stay on the same row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this:

```
area.AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.LabelAutoFitStyles.None;
```